# problem with update manager and software center

Tags: installation, updates

```
E:Type 'http://pastebin.ubuntu-gr.org/f50818e5c' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

That is the message when I try to update.  When I try to open software center its not opening!

Answer (score 1):

edit the file with gedit

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment out (add a # at the very front) or delete line 1.

Save and exit.

If you want us to review the line, post it here.